# PHP shell_exec not working with grep and pipes

Tags: php, grep, shell-exec

I've been trying to get this shell_exec() command to work in my PHP script, but it continually returns nothing. I have run it successfully from command line and get expected results.

Can someone please help debug?

```
$cmd ="/bin/grep \"John Smith\" -oPr --include=\"*.txt\" --exclude=\"title.txt\"|/usr/bin/sort|/usr/bin/uniq -c";
$rs = exec($cmd);
echo "Command: $cmd<br/>";
echo "[$rs]<br/>";
```

Many Thanks!

Comment: Check the current working directory using `getcwd()`. I ran your code and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
--exclude=\"title.txt\"|
```

by

```
--exclude=\"title.txt\" <DIRECTORY_TO_SEARCH> |
```

Answer (score 1):

`exec()` has been disabled for security reasons on your server 
This function is disabled when PHP is running in safe mode.

To enable `exec()` in php ,

if your working on wamp server

stop wamp server 
open `php.ini` file check disable_functions
comment disable_functions by just adding  semi colon (;) before disable_functions

see as shown bellow

```
; disable_functions = glob, filter_list, chown, chmod, get_current_user, php_uname, putenv, getmyuid, getmypid, dl, ini_alter, ini_restore, exec, passthru, system, popen, pclose, leak, mysql_list_dbs, listen, chgrp, disk_total_space, disk_free_space, rmdir, tmpfile, link, shell_exec, proc_open, chroot, openlog, closelog, syslog, flock, socket_create_listen, socket_accept, socket_listen, sleep, umask, set_include_path, restore_include_path, symlink, imagerotate
```

save file and 
start wamp server now again
and try again.